# Looping Fundamentals

Tags: javascript, loops, decrement

Can someone please let me know where I went wrong here? When I run the code, I get 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10.  How would I make the loop stop at 0?  When I remove the last line of code (console.log(countDown);), the loop ends at 0 but the challenge isn't completed.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Using a for loop, decrement countDown by one each time the loop runs until it equals 0, making use of looping functionality instead of logging each number separately.

```
let countDown = 10;
// ADD CODE HERE
for (let countDown = 10; countDown>0;countDown--)
{
  console.log(countDown);
}

// Uncomment the below line to check your work
console.log(countDown) // -> should print 0;
```

Comment: Is it possible you have two variables? The outer one that you define as 10. And the use used in the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that you have two `countDown` variables in your code, one at the top and one declared as a loop variable, in the initialization part of the `for` loop.

They both are different variables. Your loop is terminated correctly but when you log the `countDown` variable after the loop, you are not logging the one used in the loop, you are logging the one declared above the loop.

You don't need to declare `countDown` variable in loop, just use the one declared above the loop.

```js
let countDown = 10;

for (; countDown > 0; countDown--) {
  console.log(countDown);
}

console.log(countDown) // -> should print 0;
```

Comment: You beat me to it. 

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with looping - it's a problem with variable scope. See this link for what scope is: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))

```
let countDown = 10; // global scope - visible everywhere

for (let countDown = 10; countDown>0;countDown--) // local scope -- visible only in the loop
{
  console.log(countDown);  // this is again the inner variable with local scope
}

console.log(countDown) // the global scope variable again, hence 10;
```

To the issue itself, in fact you have two variables with the same name `countdown`. One defined outside the loop, and the other in the loop declaration. The latter shadows (hides) the former, thus any changes done to the inner variable - with a smaller scope, encompassing only the loop body - are not visible after the loop ends. So, in fact, your code does not change the value of the outer `countdown`.

To make it work, don't declare the inner variable, and reuse the outer one as the loop counter:

```
let countDown = 10;

for (; countDown > 0; countDown--) {
    console.log(countDown);
}

console.log(countDown);
```